# Git workflow for dealing with dependent PRs

Tags: git

Say when you are developing you make some tooling changes or refactor some code that you will effect future features. If you then decide to branch from your 1st PR, it becomes tedious and error-prone to manage updating from master. You have to remember which branch is based on which.

If you need to make changes to PR1, you will then have to remember to rebase PR2 each time. If PR1 gets delayed then you need to cherry-pick your commits from PR2, but if they depend on PR1 it can become super complex quickly. Accidentally merging master into PR1 will make things even more difficult.

Are there any strategies to working on dependent PRs apart from getting your PRs merged faster?

---

### Options

*From suggestions*

**Speed up merging**

- Split up components to avoid merge conflicts. Branches should only touch
  a single component.
- Place a CODEOWNERS file in sub-dirs and allow the owner to merge directly without needs PR review for small changes.

**IntelliJ changesets (just thought of it)**

- Keep one PR open at at time and use changesets instead of commits for dependent features. This is basically an easier way to cherry-pick. Changesets support hunks so you can make multiple changes to the same file and keep two separate changesets too. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html

Comment: In my team we tried many things and only thing that worked apart from small and quickly merged PRs (which aren't always possible) was breaking project into components with well defined versioned interfaces.

Comment: Batch your updating so you update all the branches at once, to reduce context switching.